# Cannot Implicitly convert type int[] to int

Tags: c#

I created a player class and I am trying to use my player class to delete a player for my menu driven player program but I keep getting the error: Cannot Implicitly convert type int[] to int'  with my ProcessDelete method. My ProcessDelete method is suppose to delete all the data of a player when the user enters a players number.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
     static Int32 ProcessDelete( Player[] players, Int32 RemoveAt)
        {

            Int32[] newIndicesArray = new Int32[players.Length - 1];

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < players.Length)
            {
                if (i != RemoveAt)
                {
                    newIndicesArray[j] = players[i];
                    j++;
                }

                i++;
            }

            return newIndicesArray;
        }


        static void DeletePlayer(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
            Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to delete
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {

                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);


                if (playerindex != -1)
                {

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}",  players[playerindex].Number, firstName[playerindex], lastName[playerindex], players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists);
                        Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        ProcessDelete(players);
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProcessDelete` method returns an array, but its signature specifies that it should return an `int`.

You're not doing anything with the return value anyway, so just change the signature to `void`:

```
static void ProcessDelete( Player[] players, Int32 RemoveAt)
```

And remove the `return` line from the end of that method:

```
return newIndicesArray;  // remove this
```

---

FWIW, you might consider using a `List<Player>` collection instead of a `Player[]` array.

Once you have the index, you could easily remove the element you need by using [`RemoveAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx), and the entire `ProcessDelete()` method could just go away.

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>;
...
// some code to add players
...
int indexToRemove = GetPlayerIndex(...);

players.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
```

Comment: That's his problem +1.  Seems like he'll want the return value, but the whole thing is so convoluted I can't make sense of it

Answer (score 0):

In your ProcessDelete method, you're returning an array of integers but your method signature says it returns a single int. I'm guessing you meant to return one of i or j?

Answer (score 0):

Converting `Int32[]` to `Int32` is not allowed try this:

```
static Int32[] ProcessDelete( Player[] players, Int32 RemoveAt) //Change Int32 to In32[]
    {
        Int32[] newIndicesArray = new Int32[players.Length - 1];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < players.Length)
        {
            if (i != RemoveAt)
            {
                newIndicesArray[j] = players[i];
                j++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return newIndicesArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should change your function's data type because it returns an array of integers, so it must have the signature as below:

```cs
static Int32[] ProcessDelete(...)
```